# ¿Por que no me funciona el if?

Tags: java, if, bucle-for

Ingresar el resultado de 4 partidos disputados entre el equipo A y el equipo B.
Determinar e informar la cantidad de partidos ganados por cada uno y el ganador de mas partidos si no obtuvieron iguales resultados.

Esta vez mi problema es que si ingreso la misma cantidad de partidos ganados (para ambos equipos) me pone que el equipo B es el que tiene mas cantidad de equipos ganados , cuando tendria que decirme empate.

```
    int partidos = 5;
    int equipoA = 0;
    int equipoB = 0;
    int partidosGanados1 = 0;
    int partidosGanados2 = 0;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i < partidos; i++) {

        System.out.println(i + "Ingrese goles del equipo A : ");
        equipoA = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i + "Ingrese goles del equipo B : ");
        equipoB = teclado.nextInt();

        if (equipoA > equipoB) {

            partidosGanados1++;
            System.out.println("Gana equipo A .");
        }

        if (equipoB > equipoA) {

            partidosGanados2++;

            System.out.println("Gana equipo B .");

        }

    }

    if (equipoA != equipoB) {

        if (equipoA > equipoB)

        {

            System.out.println("El ganador de mas partidos es el equipo A. ");
        }

        else {

            System.out.println("El ganador de mas partidos es el equipo B. ");
        }

        System.out.println("No hay empate.");
    }

    else if (equipoA == equipoB ) {

        System.out.println("Empate.");
    }

    System.out.println("Cantidad de partidos ganados por el equipo A : " + partidosGanados1);
    System.out.println("Cantidad de partidos ganados por el equipo B : " + partidosGanados2);
```

Comment: Solo estas almacenando los ultimos valores... Dime que valores estan introduciendo ?

Comment: Es un error de semantica.. estas comparando los goles.. y vos queres comparar los partidos ganados. La variable no es equipoA, es partidosGanados1...

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi ahora cambie de variable y funciona :D .Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema era que no comparabas las variables que estaban almacenando los resultados por cada ciclo:

Intenta asi :

```
int partidos = 5;
int equipoA = 0;
int equipoB = 0;
int partidosGanados1 = 0;
int partidosGanados2 = 0;

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 1; i < partidos; i++) {

    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese goles del equipo A : ");
    equipoA = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese goles del equipo B : ");
    equipoB = teclado.nextInt();

    if (equipoA > equipoB) {

        partidosGanados1++;
        System.out.println("Gana equipo A .");
    }
    else if (equipoB > equipoA) {

        partidosGanados2++;
        System.out.println("Gana equipo B .");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Hubo Empate .");
    }

}

if (partidosGanados1 != partidosGanados2) {

    if (partidosGanados1 > partidosGanados2)

    {

        System.out.println("El ganador de mas partidos es el equipo A. ");
    }

    else {

        System.out.println("El ganador de mas partidos es el equipo B. ");
    }

    System.out.println("No hay empate.");
}
else{

    System.out.println("Empate.");
}

System.out.println("Cantidad de partidos ganados por el equipo A : " + partidosGanados1);
System.out.println("Cantidad de partidos ganados por el equipo B : " + partidosGanados2);
```

Comment: Ah listooo Muchas Gracias , no podia ver el problema ahora me di cuenta y funciona :D . Saludos!

Comment: De nada Bro, siempre es un placer porder ayudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Amigo la falla esta al comparar las variables, en lugar de comparar las variables de partidosGanados1 y partidosGanados2, estas comparando equipoA y equipoB.
Además me gustaría darte un par de consejos respecto a tu código que puede que te beneficie para reducir el numero de lineas que escribes y te ayudará a comprender un poquito mejor los if/else.

Checa lo y ojala te sirve, saludos.

```
int partidos = 5;
int equipoA = 0;
int equipoB = 0;
int partidosGanados1 = 0;
int partidosGanados2 = 0;

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 1; i < partidos; i++) {

    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese goles del equipo A : ");
    equipoA = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i + "Ingrese goles del equipo B : ");
    equipoB = teclado.nextInt();

    if (equipoA > equipoB) 
    {

        partidosGanados1++;
        System.out.println("Gana equipo A .");
    }

    else if(equipoA<equipoB)
    {

        partidosGanados2++;

        System.out.println("Gana equipo B .");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Es empate");
    }

}
 if (partidosGanados1 > partidosGanados2)
 {
      System.out.println("El ganador de mas partidos es el equipo A. ");
      System.out.println("No hay empate.");
 }

 else if(partidosGanados1 < partidosGanados2)
 {

     System.out.println("El ganador de mas partidos es el equipo B. ");
     System.out.println("No hay empate.");
 }
 else
 {
     System.out.println("Hay empate");
 }

System.out.println("Cantidad de partidos ganados por el equipo A : " + partidosGanados1);
System.out.println("Cantidad de partidos ganados por el equipo B : " + partidosGanados2);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :D , si era ese el problema jaja , saludos !